# Atomic Increment int value of entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

We need to be able to increment an `int` property of our entities in atomic fashion.

What I can image to use is the [Batch Update](https://entityframework-plus.net/batch-update) from the entityframework-plus nuget package.

The package has a method which can execute an update sql query given an `IQueryable` which would change the values directly in the database.

So image we have the class

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public int Key1 { get; set; }

    public int Key2 { get; set; }

    public int Version { get; set }
}
```

then I could have code like

```cs
DbSet<Foo> dbSet;

Foo foo = ...;

foo.ToQuery(dbSet)
    .UpdateFromQuery(x => new Foo { Version = x.Version + 1 });
```

the only missing part is the `ToQuery` method, which I image would need a signature like

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> ToQuery<T>(this T entity, DbSet<T> dbSet)
```

So overall my question is, is there a way to convert an entity object (retrieved from an `DbContext`) to an valid `IQueryable` for the same `DbContext`.

Or does anyone have a better idea how to increment an `int` value directly on the DB without generating the SQL oneself.

Comment: Wrap it in the transaction?

Comment: Sadly this does not help in my scenario and it would a bit offtopic for this question to explain why. It is sadly also not an option to lock the db row for the lifetime of the entity. Thats why I need the atomic increment.

Comment: how many instances of the app you have running?

Comment: The answer is no. You need `dbSet.Where(...)` matching your object(s), e.g. `dbSet.Where(x => x.Id == foo.Id)`